# Proper closing application with FileStream.Read

Tags: c#, filestream

In some place I call

```
Task.Run(new Action(Read));
```

this call starts task in other thread:

```
private void Read()
{
    while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        int bytesReaded = deviceStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }
}
```

This thread blocks while Read try to get some data from file (this is not usual file, this is device). then I close application, form closed, but application still runing. I tried Close and Dispose on deviceStream but not helped - its still wait to Read completed. Interrupting thread not recommended by Microsoft.

The main goal is read data non-stop, but data arrives from device by pieces, and pause between pieces can be huge, so Read can be blocked for the long time.

Questions: Is there some method to gracefully interrupt Read? Is there another pattern can be implemented to achieve my goal (with BeginRead/EndRead maybe, but readed here that EndRead also blocks and can't be interrupted.

PS: I see new method in MSDN ReadAsync, but can't imagine how I can use it (there I need restart Read)

Comment: Can you describe what is deviceStream ?

Comment: Crystal ball says that it is actually the Close() call that deadlocks, show us a stack trace.  If not then you'll need to go shopping for a better device driver for the device.  You'll get the best advice from whomever you got the driver from.

Comment: @progpow deviceStream = new FileStream(deviceHandle, FileAccess.ReadWrite, bufferSize, true);

Comment: @HansPassant without blocked on deviceStream.Read. Then called deviceStream.Close() no blocking. Device is my device driver. May be I make error then develop driver. I just try read and close COM1 device, and   my app closed as should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not FileStream.Read issue, I blocked ReadDispatcher in driver using KeWait... function.

Answer (score 0):

You can you a ReadTimeout property if the device stream provides it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readtimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: CanTimeout property for this stream = false

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it`s helpful for you:

```
private void Read()
{
    while (!cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        if(deviceStream.CanRead && deviceStream.Length > 0)
            int bytesReaded = deviceStream.Read(buffer, 0, Math.Min(bufferSize, deviceStream.Length));
    }
}
```

Of course when you dispose you need call cancel request

Comment: @Vakyob i made changes, if your stream support it, then it will work.

Comment: I see your changes, and I see u don't understand situation. "Read" blocks thread, so next check in your if() will be reached then read or read error occured. If no data to read thread blocked and no checks at this moment.

Comment: @Vakyob Loop entered to read only when it has data, after read it check else one, if stream hasn't data loop skip if. I made else one changes - stream read only buffer frame or all data from stream. But until i don't know, is support or not your stream Length property.

Comment: Sorry progpow, I think u write your theory, not practice. CanRead property only indicates if stream supports reading (some streams can be only writeable), it actually not show if stream have data. Thus in my case if(deviceStream.CanRead) always true. 2nd, about Length property. Read already works in such way without additional checks. If data in stream greater then buffer size it read only bufferSize bytes, if Length less, it reads Lenth bytes and return bytesReaded = Length.

Comment: @Vakyob, ok then if length == 0, then you don't enter to Read, and always exit from `while`, when cancel call. And it`s strange then close() and dispose() not release resource.